# How to implement authentication in multiple "Areas" of asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, areas

I have an asp.net mvc application.
The application is virtually separated by "Areas".
Both Areas have their own Login controllers for authentication.
Both Areas have their own Home controllers.

Questions:

How do I implement forms authentication in both areas as there 
is one web.config for both the areas? The web.config is in the root 
of the application and not in individual folders of the Area folder.

How do I set the startup "Area"? i.e. Which Area's Home controller 
should be called first when the project runs?